# My debian server have a dynamic ip address. Have one program like a vpn to give

Tags: debian, vpn, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have a problem with a debian server. I need put a website to work, but my desktop doesn't have a Static IP, only a dynamic IP. The internet provider creat a lot of dificulties to upgrade my internet to statics IPs, I tried to put in he a DDNS, but I wanted a Static IP to this machine.

So I have an idea and I wanted to know if is possible install in this machine a VPN or something that an dedicated IP, to configure My Website. Have some program or something that do it service?

Put a program or something that give a Static IP in my server.

Answer (score 1):

There might be VPN providers out there that will allow port forwarding but I don't think this is very common.

Another option would be to use ngrok basically it will create a URL pointing back to your local web server on-the-fly.
(this is an oversimplification)

[website here](https://ngrok.com/)

It will generate a URL that looks something like this:

> ngrok.com/mywebsitehere

LocalTunnel is a very interesting project too that does something similar:

[Link here](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/)

And a bunch more:

[Alternatives here](https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling)

Another option would be to get yourself a VPS somewhere and use that either as a 'VPN' to route traffic back to your server. Quite easily done with SSH. Or just run your code there. This would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I understand, but I want a IP to my server, in these shapes will be like a DDNS. About the VPN with port forwarding, do you know some?